# How to programmatically get images commonly used in Eclipse Plug-ins

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

What are the places to look for if a plug-in wishes to re-use images that are defined by other plug-ins.

For example, where to look for if a plug-in needed the 'Terminate' icon, defined somewhere in the debug plug-in.

Now and then I have been searching for images and though it would be useful to list the locations of commonly used images in one place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some of the platform plug-ins make (some of) their images available though `ImageDescriptor`s. Unfortunately all in a slightly different way.

**Platform UI - org.eclipse.ui**

This plug-in defines images for public use in `ISharedImages`. To obtain an image descriptor, query the workbench's image registry like this:

```java
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getSharedImages().getImage( ISharedImages.IMG_OBJ_FILE );
```

**IDE - org.eclipse.ui.ide**

The IDE plug-in adds some more images to the workbench image registry and lists the registered names in `IDE.ISharedImages`.

To obtain an image descriptor, also query the workbench's image registry like this:

```java
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getSharedImages().getImage( IDE.ISharedImages.IMG_OBJ_PROJECT );
```

**Debug - org.eclipse.ui.debug**

The debug plug-in defines shared images in `IDebugUIConstants`, image name constants start with `IMG_`. They can be access through the `DebugUITools` utility class.

For example:

```java
DebugUITools.getImageDescriptor( IDebugUIConstants.IMG_ACT_RUN );
```

**Compare - org.eclipse.compare**

The compare plug-in defines ImageDescritpors for *Next* and *Previous* images directly in `CompareUI`.

For example:

```java
ImageDescriptor next = CompareUI.DESC_DTOOL_NEXT;
```

**Team - org.eclipse.team.ui**

The team plug-in as well uses a `ISharedImage` interface to declare overlay images to decorate modified, conflicting, etc. resources.

The image descriptors can be obtained through the `TeamImages` class:

```
ImageDescriptor imageDescriptor = TeamImages.getImageDescriptor( ISharedImages.IMG_DIRTY_OVR );
```

**JDT - org.eclipse.jdt.ui**

JDT aligns with the workbench when providing images. Its `ISharedImages` interface defines the registered names and `JavaUI.getSharedImages()` allows to obtain the respective image descrptors.

**Directly Accessing Images**

`AbstractUIPlugin` has a static helper method to get a descriptor of an image in an arbitrary plug-in.

```java
ImageDescriptor imageDescriptor = AbstractUIPlugin.imageDescriptorFromPlugin( "the.bundle.id", "/icons/sample-image.png" );
```

**Warning:** Loading images in this way is risky and should generally be avoided. Image locations are not part of a plug-ins API and a plug-in author may choose to delete or move the image which will break your code. If you need proof that this actually happens, have a look at [this post](https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/eclipse-dev/msg10014.html).

If you need an image from a plug-in that doesn't make it available through its API, you should prefer to place a copy of that image within your plug-in.